# Fillna not working when combined with groupby and mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The below code filters my Dataframe for 5 rows with Zambia as the Country Name.

```
df2.loc[df2['Country Name'] == 'Zambia'].head(5)

Country Name    Year    CO2
262    Zambia   1960    NaN
526    Zambia   1961    NaN
790    Zambia   1962    NaN
1054   Zambia   1963    NaN
1318   Zambia   1964    0.949422
```

Next, shown below is the average Zambia CO2 value.

```
df2.groupby('Country Name', as_index=False)['CO2'].mean().loc[df2['Country Name'] == 'Zambia']

    Country Name    CO2
262   Zambia      0.484002
```

Finally, I now try to fill in all the NaN values with the average value. Notice only the first NaN value actually gets filled in. Why is this and how can I make sure all NaN values get filled in with the average of each country?

```
df2['CO2'] = df2['CO2'].fillna(value = df2.groupby('Country Name', as_index=False)['CO2'].mean()['CO2'])

    Country Name  Year    CO2
262    Zambia     1960   0.484002
526    Zambia     1961    NaN
790    Zambia     1962    NaN
1054   Zambia     1963    NaN
1318   Zambia     1964   0.949422
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the optional argument `inplace=True` to the call to `fillna`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` filled by aggregate values with same size like original `DataFrame`, so `fillna` working nice:

```
s = df2.groupby('Country Name')['CO2'].transform('mean')
df2['CO2'] = df2['CO2'].fillna(value = s)
```